# Limit of definite integral of $f(x)\cos(mx)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, limits, riemann-integration

Source: Old comp./preliminary exam.

Let $f(x)$ be a Riemann integrable function on $[0,1]$. Prove that $$\lim_{m\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\cos(mx) \, \,dx=0$$

Thought

$(1)$ Because we don't know if $f(x)$ is differentiable, we can only use integration by part by setting $du=f(x)\, \,dx$ and $v=\cos(mx)$, the result is not quite helpful.

$(2)$ We don't know whether $f(x)\cos(mx)$ converges as $m\rightarrow \infty$ so those convergence theorems cannot be applied.

Side note: This exam assume no knowledge in measure theory and Lebesgue integral.

Comment: You know you can approximate $f$ by a step function.

Comment: Hint: Bessel Inequality

Comment: OP, go to baby Rudin pg. 188. I think that it may be the best place to find an answer that suits your needs.

You can even find almost exactly the question you are asking in pg. 190, line 3.

Comment: @Aloizio Macedo, OK, thanks, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $f$ is Riemann integrable, it is bounded and continuous almost everywhere on $[a,b]$. Also it is Lebesgue integrable. By Lusin's theorem, there is a continuous function $g$ on $[a,b]$ that
$$
m(\{x:f(x)\ne g(x), \:x\in[a,b]\})<\epsilon
$$
Note $g$ is also bounded on $[a,b]$. Then
\begin{align}
\left|\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\cos(mx) \, dx\right|&=\left|\int_{a}^{b}(f(x)-g(x))\cos(mx) \, dx+\int_{a}^{b}g(x)\cos(mx) \, dx\right|
\\
&=\left|\int_{\{x:f\ne g, \:x\in[a,b]\}}(f(x)-g(x))\cos(mx) \, dx+\int_{a}^{b}g(x)\cos(mx) \, dx\right|
\\
&\leqslant \epsilon M+\left|\int_{a}^{b}g(x)\cos(mx) \, dx\right|
\\
\end{align}
So $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\cos(mx) \, dx\to0$ if $\int_{a}^{b}g(x)\cos(mx) \, dx\to0$. Thus we only prove it for continuous function.

First on any interval $[c,d]$, there is
\begin{align}
\left|\int_c^d\cos(mx)dx\right|&=\left|\dfrac1{m}\int_{mc}^{md}\cos(y)dy\right|
\\
&=\left|\dfrac1{m}\int_{mc}^{2n\pi}\cos(y)dy+\sum\limits_{k=n}^{l}\dfrac1{m}\int_{2k\pi}^{2(k+1)\pi}\cos(y)dy+\dfrac1{m}\int_{2(l+1)\pi}^{md}\cos(y)dy\right|
\\
&\leqslant\dfrac{2n\pi-mc+md-2(l+1)\pi}{m}
\\
&\leqslant\dfrac{4\pi}{m}\tag{1}
\end{align}
where $n=\left[\dfrac{mc}{2\pi}\right]+1,l=\left[\dfrac{md}{2\pi}\right]-1$.

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[a, b]$. Since $f(x)$ is uniform continuous on $[a,b]$, for any $\epsilon>0,\space\exists \delta>0, \space \forall y_1,y_2\in [a,b], |y_1-y_2|<\delta$, there is $|f(y_1)-f(y_2)|<\epsilon \space$.

Let $\mathcal{P} = \{x_{0}, x_{1}, x_{2},\ldots, x_{n}\}$ of $[a, b]$ be a partition that $\max\{|x_{k - 1}-x_{k}|\}<\delta,\: k\in[1,n]$. There is
\begin{align}
\left|\int_a^bf(x)\cos(mx)dx-\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}\int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}}f(x_i)\cos(mx)dx\right|&=\left|\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}\int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}}(f(x)-f(x_i))\cos(mx)dx\right|
\\
&\leqslant\epsilon\int_a^b|\cos(mx)|dx
\\
&\leqslant(b-a)\epsilon\tag{2}
\end{align}

And by $(1)$
\begin{align}
\left|\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}\int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}}f(x_i)\cos(mx)dx\right|&=\left|\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}f(x_i)\int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}}\cos(mx)dx\right|
\\
&\leqslant\dfrac{4\pi}{m}nM\tag{3}
\end{align}
where $|f(x_i)|\leqslant M$.

From $(2),(3)$, we have
\begin{align}
\left|\int_a^bf(x)\cos(mx)dx\right|&\leqslant\left|\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}\int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}}f(x_i)\cos(mx)dx\right|+(b-a)\epsilon
\\
&\leqslant\dfrac{4\pi nM}{m}+(b-a)\epsilon
\end{align}
And
$$
\varlimsup\limits_{m\to\infty}\left|\int_a^bf(x)\cos(mx)dx\right|\leqslant (b-a)\epsilon
$$
Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary small, we have
$$
\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\int_a^bf(x)\cos(mx)dx=0 
$$

Comment: Thanks for the long work with fundamental approach. I'm not fully convinced by the argument in the end, though. It looks like the value of $n$ depends on $\epsilon$ and in order to get $\epsilon$ arbitrarily small, $n$ could be arbitrarily large.

Comment: Thanks, Bungo. I modify it to $g=f$ on $[a,b]$ except for arbitrary small interval.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a proof that uses no Lebesgue machinery.

Fix $\epsilon > 0$.

Since $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$, there exists a partition $P$ defined by the points $0=x_0 < x_1 < \ldots < x_N = 1$ such that
$$0 \leq \int_0^1 f(x) dx - \sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n(x_n - x_{n-1}) < \epsilon$$
where $a_n = \inf_{x \in [x_{n-1}, x_n]} f(x)$. In other words, $f$ can be approximated from below by a step function, such that the approximation error is less than $\epsilon$.

The inequality can be rewritten as
$$0 \leq \sum_{n=1}^{N}\int_{x_{n-1}}^{x_n} (f(x) - a_n) dx < \epsilon$$
Therefore,
$$\begin{aligned}
\left|\sum_{n=1}^{N}\int_{x_{n-1}}^{x_n} (f(x) - a_n) \cos(mx) dx\right|
& \leq \sum_{n=1}^{N}\int_{x_{n-1}}^{x_n} |f(x) - a_n| dx \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{N}\int_{x_{n-1}}^{x_n} (f(x) - a_n) dx \\
&< \epsilon
\end{aligned}$$
Now, we compute
$$\left|\int_{x_{n-1}}^{x_n}a_n \cos(mx) dx\right| = \frac{|a_n|}{m}\left|\sin(mx_n) - \sin(mx_{n-1})\right| \leq \frac{2|a_n|}{m}$$
Now choose $m$ large enough that $\displaystyle \frac{2|a_n|}{m} < \frac{\epsilon}{N}$ for all $1 \leq n \leq N$. We then can conclude that
$$\begin{aligned}
\left|\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\cos(mx)dx\right| &= 
\left|\sum_{n=1}^{N}\int_{x_{n-1}}^{x_n} f(x)\cos(mx) dx\right| \\
&\leq \left|\sum_{n=1}^{N}\int_{x_{n-1}}^{x_n} (f(x) - a_n)\cos(mx) dx\right|
+ \left|\sum_{n=1}^{N}\int_{x_{n-1}}^{x_n} a_n \cos(mx) dx\right| \\
&\leq \epsilon + N\left(\frac{\epsilon}{N}\right) \\
&= 2\epsilon
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: I was at first a bit intimidated to work through the details of this solution -- but now that I have, I just think it's such a cool and cute proof.  Thanks so much @Bungo.  Can I ask you one quick follow-up question?  In the assumption of $f$ being Riemann integrable (since it is continuous over the closed interval [0,1]), would approximating f from *above* change the outcome?  I am guessing not, since I think that the limit of the lower integrals equals the limit of the upper integrals, and the limit of the lower Riemann sums equals the limit of the upper Riemmann sums.

Comment: But I just wanted to confirm - thanks so much @Bungo

Comment: @LebronJames: Actually the hypothesis is that $f$ is Riemann integrable, not necessarily continuous. (Continuous implies Riemann integrable but not vice versa.) Approximating from above would also work. I chose to approximate from below just for the convenience of having $|f(x) - a_n| = f(x) - a_n$.

Comment: @LebronJames: If you approximate from above, you will simply have $|f(x) - a_n| = a_n - f(x)$. The proof should still go through just fine.

Comment: Ok, got it -- thanks so much @Bungo.  Have a great night :-)

Answer (score 2):

The set $\{e^{\pi imx}\}_{m\in \mathbb{Z}}$ is a basis of $L^2(0,1)$. So $f(x)=\sum_{j\in \mathbb{Z}}a_je^{\pi ijx}$ when $f\in L^2(0,1)$. So $\int_{0}^1f(x)e^{\pi ijx}dx=(f,e^{\pi ijx})=a_j$. For the other hand, $\lim_ja_j=0$ because $f$ is Riemann integrable so bounded and so $f\in L^2(0,1)$. In particular, taking the real part of $a_j$ we have $\lim_j \int_{0}^1f(x)\cos(jx)dx=0.$

Comment: Although a correct answer, OP states explicitly: "This exam assume no knowledge in measure theory and Lebesgue integral."

Comment: This is a sweet approach - I was thinking Fourier while reading the question.  It might not be what the OP wanted but other questions redirect here and I think it has value.  One problem though is that Riemann integrable functions are not necessarily bounded.  It would be nice to see this expanded to account for that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simplified solution.

As explained in other post, we only prove it for continuous function.

Since
$$
\int_{a+(k-1)\frac{2\pi}m}^{a+k\frac{2\pi}m}\cos(mx)\,dx=0\tag{1}
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\int_a^bf(x)\cos(mx)\,dx\right|
&\leqslant\left|\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{a+(k-1)\frac{2\pi}m}^{a+k\frac{2\pi}m}f(x)\cos(mx)\,dx\right|+\left|\int_{a+n\frac{2\pi}m}^bf(x)\cos(mx)\,dx\right|\\
&=\left|\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{a+(k-1)\frac{2\pi}m}^{a+k\frac{2\pi}m}\left(f(x)-f\left(a+k\tfrac{2\pi}m\right)\right)\cos(mx)\,dx\right|\tag{by (1)}\\
&+\left|\int_{a+n\frac{2\pi}m}^bf(x)\cos(mx)\,dx\right|\tag{2}
\end{align}
where $n=\left\lfloor(b-a)\frac{m}{2\pi}\right\rfloor$, and $\left|b-a-n\frac{2\pi}m\right|\le\frac{2\pi}m$.

Since $f$ is uniform continuous, given $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ that for any $x,y\in[a,b]$, $\:|x-y|<\delta$, there is $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. Now let $m$ large enough so that $\frac{2\pi}m<\delta<\epsilon$. From $(2)$, there is
$$
\left|\int_a^bf(x)\cos(mx)\,dx\right|\leqslant(b-a)\epsilon+\frac{2\pi}m M<\epsilon(b-a+M)
$$
where $M=\sup_{x\in[a,b]}|f(x)|$.