# How can I show that this sequence of integrals goes to zero?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, limits, fourier-analysis

$$\int_0^{2\pi} f(x)\cos(nx)dx$$

for $f(x)$ real valued and continuous on $[0,2\pi]$.

How can I show that the limit of the integrals, as n goes to infinity, is zero?

I have thought of and tried integration by parts, with not much insight gained.

I also thought that perhaps the Fourier transform is lurking in the background of this problem, but I'm not sure how to utilize it.

Comment: f(x) per cycle becomes a fixed value close to the limit and since the integral of a cycle, when f(x) is a fixed value is zero, should help you get to the proof.

Comment: In fact, from the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma, one only needs $f$ to be $L^1$.  See [THIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma#Statement) for a proof that relies on the fact that $f$ can be approximated in the $L^1$ norm by a compactly supported smooth function ([SEE THIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Locally_compact_version).

Comment: On the other hand, if you don't know the Lebesgue theory, the Riemann integral suffices since your function is continuous. Here is a straightforward proof which uses the fact that any Riemann integrable function can be approximated by a step function, where the result follows from a simple calculation: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1408615/169852

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit @Moti?  What do you mean when you say that f(x) per cycle becomes a fixed value?  I have never heard of this before.  Are you referring to periodic / elliptic functions, for example?  And why is the integral of a cycle when f(x) is a fixed value equal to zero?  I'm very interested in your ideas to help me construct this proof.  If you know of a good online reference too, please feel free to provide the link so that I can read further.  Thanks,

Comment: Thanks @Bungo.   I will study this solution in detail.

Comment: What @Moti means is that as $n$ increases, the period of $\cos(nx)$ becomes smaller and smaller. Now $f$ is uniformly continuous (because it is continuous on a closed, bounded interval), so as $n$ becomes sufficiently large, $f$ will be approximately constant over any single period (what Moti is calling a cycle) of $\cos(nx)$. So the integral of $f(x) \cos(nx)$ over one period will be approximately the integral of a constant times $\cos(nx)$ over that period, which is equal to zero. Of course you will need to fill in the details to make this rigorous.

Comment: @Bungo Thanks for a great explanation. With all those comments I believe that the question was answered.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, I'll give you a proof that relies only on uniform continuity of $f$ and the Riemann integral.

For any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-y| < \delta$ and $x,y\in[0,2\pi]$. This can be done because $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,2\pi]$. Choose $N$ large enough that $2\pi/N < \delta$. Define $x_j=j\frac{2\pi}{N}$ for $j=0,1,2,\cdots,N$. Let
$$
              x_j^{\star}=\frac{1}{2}(x_{j-1}+x_j).
$$
Then
$$
              |f(x)-f(x_j^{\star})| < \epsilon/4\pi \mbox{ whenever } x \in [x_{j-1},x_j].
$$
Define $f_N(x)$ so that $f(x)=f(x_j^{\star})$ for $x \in [x_{j-1},x_j)$. This works fine for all of the intervals up to $j=N$. For $j=N$, let $f_N(x)=f(x_N^{\star})$ for $x \in [x_{j-1},x_j]$. Then
$$
                     |f(x)-f_N(x)| < \epsilon/4\pi, \;\;\; x \in [0,2\pi].
$$
Then
$$
   \left|\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)\cos(nx)dx-\int_{0}^{2\pi}f_N(x)\cos(nx)dx\right| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}.
$$
And
\begin{align}
      \int_{0}^{2\pi}f_N(x)\cos(nx)dx 
   & = \sum_{j=1}^{N}f(x_j^{\star})\int_{x_{j-1}}^{x_j}\cos(nx)dx \\
   & = \sum_{j=1}^{N}f(x_j^{\star})\frac{\sin(nx_{j})-\sin(nx_{j-1})}{n}.
\end{align}
Now you can choose $K$ large enough that the sum on the right is bounded by $\epsilon/2$ whenever $n > K$. It follows that
$$
         \left|\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)\cos(nx)dx\right| < \epsilon \mbox{ whenever } n > K.
$$