# Can I use my approach to show that the integral of $f(x)\cos(nx)$, over one period, goes to zero?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, convergence-divergence

Here's my work, without measure theory (Riemann-Lebesgue lemma) and without step function approximations:

Let $f(x)$ be continuous on the closed interval $[0,2\pi]$, and $x$ a real variable.

Then we have that

$$0 \le \big|\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)\cos(nx)dx \big| $$
$$\le \big(\int_0^{2\pi}f^2(x)dx \big)^{\frac{1}{2}} \big(\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^2(nx)dx \big)^{\frac{1}{2}} $$
$$\le (\max_{[0,2\pi]}[f^2(x)]2\pi)^{\frac{1}{2}} \big(\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^2(nx)dx \big)^{\frac{1}{2}} $$
$$\le C \big(\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^2(nx)dx \big)^{\frac{1}{2}} $$
$$\le C \big(\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(2nx)+1}{2}dx \big)^{\frac{1}{2}} $$
$$\le C \big(\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}(\cos(2nx)+1)dx \big)^{\frac{1}{2}} $$
$$\le D \big(\int_0^{4\pi n}(\cos(u)+1) \frac{du}{2n} \big)^{\frac{1}{2}} $$
$$\le D \big(\frac{1}{2n}\int_0^{4\pi n}(\cos(u)+1) du \big)^{\frac{1}{2}} $$

Now, letting $n$ $\to$ $\infty$, I am not sure how I can conclude that this sequence of integrals goes to zero.  The integral becomes improper, while being scaled by a factor that is going to zero.

Would this approach even work, i.e., is it at least *valid*?  I am assuming that $f(x)$ and $\cos(nx)$ are "square-integrable functions", when I used the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.  Is this ok to assume?

Also, since $f$ is continuous on the closed, bounded interval $[0,2\pi]$, we know that it attains a max on this interval.  I use this fact to claim that $f^2$ is bounded and attains a max over this same interval.  Then I let it be absorbed into a constant factor.

The last bit of my work is just rewriting trigonometric equalities and performing one substitution.

Any hints, comments or suggestions are greatly welcome :-)

Thanks.

Comment: This cannot work because $\int_0^{2\pi} \cos^2 nx dx=  \pi$.

Comment: Your esitmate is not good enough. Read https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1406142/limit-of-definite-integral-of-fx-cosmx/1406357#1406357

Comment: Thanks so much @stochasticboy321 for the nice counterexample :-)

Comment: Thanks so much for the link @hermes.  I will now buckle down and learn the step function argument to this question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not work, too much has been given away.

Calculate $\int_{2\pi k/n}^{2\pi(k+1)/n }\cos^2(nx)\,dx$. Making the change of variable $u=nx$  we  get $\frac{1}{n}$ times a positive constant. There are $n$ intervals, so the full integral is a positive constant.

Comment: Ok, got it -- thanks so much for your quick response, @AndreNicolas.  I will stick with the approaches given in the link above.  Have a great night :-)

Comment: You are welcome. An integration by parts approach might also work.

Comment: @André Nicolas, since $\cos^2(nx)>0$, I think it will not work either. It need to cancel out positive and negative part in periodic function.

Comment: Ohh, hmm...I was considering asking you for an alternate approach to the techniques shown in the link provided above -- since those solutions are pretty heavy / technical and I am not likely to remember much of it, after going through it, I think.  Now that you mentioned it, integration by parts was actually my first attempt at this problem, before going with the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality approach.  Hmm...I would love to revisit  the integration by parts approach.

Comment: But ... integrating by parts doesn't seem to offer any insight at all.  I am integrating cos(nx) and differentiating f(x) -- so I am making an extra assumption now, too, since the question only assumes continuity of f over $[0,2\pi]$.  Can you offer some suggestions with integrating by parts?  I will now try this approach again, and perhaps then search around MSE, in case there is an IBP solution to this type of question.  Thanks so much @AndreNicolas,

Comment: Hmm...maybe I'll integrate f(x) and differentiate cos(nx) instead.  The opposite strategy of what one learns in Calc I/II.  Let's see where this leads to ...

Comment: For sure we will need extra conditions, that's why the standard proofs are not at the elementary calculus level. I did not write out an argument, was thinking of $du=n\cos(nx)\,dx$, $v=\frac{1}{n}f(x)$. If the derivative is bounded,  we should be OK. But that is not the theorem we are trying to prove, we want at most continuity of $f$.

Comment: Ok, got it -- thanks again @AndréNicolas.  I just worked through Bungo's solution on the link given above.  It's no longer that scary of a solution :-)  Have a great night :-)