# Proof that $\int f(x)\sin(Nx)\ dx \to 0$ as $N \to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-series, dirichlet-series

I'm studying Fourier series out of Rudin's "Principals of Mathematical Analysis". In the proof that the Fourier series $s_N(f;x)$ converges pointwise to $f$, it assumes that at a point $x$, there is some $\delta,M>0$ such that $\vert f(x+t)-f(x)\vert \leq M\vert t\vert$ for any $t$ with $\vert t\vert<\delta$. It then goes on to show that for the Fourier series:
$$\begin{split} s_N(f;x)-f(x)&=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(f(x-t)-f(t))D_N(t)dt\\
&=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{f(x-t)-f(t)}{\sin(t/2)}\sin((N+1/2)t)dt\\
&=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{f(x-t)-f(t)}{\sin(t/2)}\cos(t/2)\sin(Nt)dt+\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(f(x-t)-f(t))\cos(Nt)dt 
\end{split}$$
The terms that aren't $\cos(Nt)$ or $\sin(Nt)$ are bounded because of the assumption about $f$, so then the book claims that the integrals tend to $0$ as $N\rightarrow\infty$. This makes total sense to me intuitively, but I have no idea how to prove it; I can't use the boundedness of the left terms in the integral without taking the absolute value, but if I do that then the trig terms of $Nt$ *don't* tend to 0, they tend to 1.

Really I'd just like to show that $\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)D_N(x)dx=f(0)$, but it's basically the same problem.

Comment: What about Riemann-Lebesgues Lemma?

Comment: Certainly you need not have $\int f(x) D_N(x)\ dx = f(0)$ for finite $N$; it will only be true in the limit. As @TheOscillator said, what you need is the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma. Just in case Rudin left this as an exercise (I don't have my copy handy), here is a proof for Riemann-integrable functions: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1408615/169852

Comment: Yeah the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma does it, though the proof on Wikipedia depends on some other results that definitely weren't covered in the course I'm taking. The proof you linked was really good; if you posted that as an answer I'd accept it.

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler proof goes as follows:

By the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, we know that the Fourier coefficient of $f$, defined as $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)e^{-inx} dx$$ goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$. Using Euler's equation, given by $$e^{ix} = cos(x) + isin(x)$$
you can conclude that the imaginary part of the integral also goes to $0$, which is precisely what you need.