# Let $f$ be Riemann Integrable on $ [0,2\pi]. $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, uniform-convergence

Let $ g(t) = \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(x)\cdot \sin(tx) dx, $ where $ t \in \mathbb{R}. $ Show that $g$ is uniformly continuous on $ \mathbb{R} $ and that $ \lim_{n \to \infty} g(n) = 0. $

I don't even know if I can assume $f$ to be continuous since not all Riemann integrable functions are continuous.

Comment: At least for the part about limit you can find some post on this site: [Limit of definite integral of $f(x)\cos(mx)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1406142). I found this one [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B2%5Cpi%7D%20f(x)%5Ccdot%20%5Csin(tx)%20dx%24&p=1). You can find more advice on searching here: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265)

Comment: For proving uniform continuity, you can use the fact that $\sin$ is uniformly continuous. Let me know if you need assistance with that. For proving the other claim, the second answer in Martin Sleziak's link does a thorough job.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thank you.

Comment: @rubikscube09 ok sin is uniformly continuous but what about f(x)? Don't we need that aswell?

Comment: For the limit part see [Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Riemann-LebesgueLemma.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll prove uniform continuity here. First, we see that $h(t)= \sin(tx)$ is a uniformly continuous function with fixed $x$ and varying $t$. This is because $\sin$ itself is uniformly continuous. Hence, for $\epsilon >0$ we can find $\delta >0$ such that:
$$
|t_1 - t_2| <\delta \implies |\sin(xt_1) - \sin(xt_2)|<\epsilon 
$$
Keeping the same $\delta$ distance between $t_1,t_2$, we conclude:
$$
|g(t_1) - g(t_2)| = \left|\int_0^{2\pi} f(x)\sin(t_1x)\mathrm{d}x - \int_0^{2\pi} f(x)\sin(t_2x)\mathrm{d}x\right| \leq \int_0^{2\pi}|f(x)||\sin(t_1x)-\sin(t_2x) \mathrm{d}x \
$$
Because $f$ is Riemann integrable, it is bounded. applying this and uniform continuity we conclude that:
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}|f(x)||\sin(t_1x)-\sin(t_2x)| \mathrm{d}x \leq \int_0^{2\pi}|f(x)|\mathrm{d}x \leq 2\pi M\epsilon
$$

Giving us uniform continuity.