# Fourier series coefficients converge to zero

Tags: fourier-series, inner-products

Let $f \in C[−\pi, \pi]$. Show that both the n-th Fourier sine and the n-th Fourier cosine coefficients of $f$ go to $0$ as $n \to +\infty$.

Hello guys. I did some work for proof but I am not sure that I am on the right track. I used Bessel's inequality and got that $\left\Vert f \right\Vert ^2 ≥ \pi \cdot \sum \left(|a_n|^2 +|b_n|^2 \right)$.

How should i continue?

Comment: Use MathJax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: You cannot "choose $f$ to be zero".  $f$ is a given continuous function on $[-\pi.\pi]$.  But Bessel's inequality is a good thing to use.

Comment: The title is very confusing, and doesn’t appear to be related to the question

Comment: Is it true for all f? So it must be true for f=0. Am i right?

Comment: yes, but showing it's true for f=0 does not show that it is true for all f, which is what the problem is asking you to do

Comment: FYI, this is called the [Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma). I'm sure you can find many proofs here. See for example [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1408615/169852), which proves it under the weaker assumption that $f$ is Riemann integrable.

Comment: thank you so much i am checking that now. However i need an algebraic proof.

Comment: Btw, if you really have established that $\pi \sum(|a_n|^2 + |b_n|^2) \leq \|f\|^2$, then you're almost done. That bound implies that $\sum |a_n|^2$ and $\sum |b_n|^2$ converge, and therefore $|a_n|^2 \to 0$ and $|b_n|^2 \to 0$, hence $a_n \to 0$ and $b_n \to 0$.

Comment: yes i established that. But how should i show your comment is true?

Comment: Which step do you need help with? A series of nonnegative terms that is bounded above by a finite number ($\|f\|^2$ in this case) is convergent. If a series is convergent, then its terms ($|a_n|^2$ and $|b_n|^2$ in this case) converge to zero. And $|a_n|^2$ converges to zero if and only if $|a_n|$ converges to zero if and only if $a_n$ converges to zero. Similarly for $b_n$.