# How to show $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_0^{2\pi}\cos(nx)f(x)dx=0$ using integration by parts?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-writing

Prove if $f∈ C^1[0, 2\pi], \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_0^{2\pi}\cos(nx)f(x)dx=0$

I understand there is a very similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1406142/limit-of-definite-integral-of-fx-cosmx), but I am specifically trying to use integration by parts.

Comment: Any properties of $f$ are assumed?

Comment: I'm not so optimistic that the "integration by parts" technique helps you out here, since integrating or differentiating $f(x)$ during that process, produces a whole new function generally.

Comment: f is assumed to be continuously differentiable on [0, 2pi], apologies for omitting that.

Comment: This is known as the Riemann Lebesgue Theorem

Answer (score 1):

If you integrate by parts and differentiate $f$ you wind up with terms involving $f'(x)$ and $\dfrac{\sin(nx)}{n}$.  The latter tends to zero uniformly.